# Width and Height not working on 'a' tags?

Tags: html, css, size, hyperlink, styling

I am new to css and started working on a few simple projects. I ran into a really weird issue styling buttons, though. The following code will not result in a link:

```
<a href="#" style="width:240px; height:40px;"></a>
```

But for some reason, this will:

```
<a href="#" style="width:240px; height:40px; float:left;"></a>
```

My question is basically, how in the world to you set the size of a link without having to use float? And why would float work?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pN99R/ It is doing the opposite of what you are saying :)

Comment: Karthikr, it actually isn't doing the opposite. If you inspect the element. The 2nd 'a' is in front. This is because it is being floated, so it pushes the other element to the right of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<a href="#" style="width:240px; height:40px;background-color:blue;display:block;"></a>
```

It is because an 'a' element is usually displayed inline. You can over-ride it by using display:block;

More on 'display' here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Regarding float:left;

When floating left, the browser automatically over-rides the display to be a block.

Answer (score 0):

Since "a" is inline element, you must display it as an inline-block

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```

to keep it inline but be able to change it's dimensions, padding, margin and basically everything else that you could do with an "div".

There is a IE7 and lower issue with `inline-block` so you may want to use css "hack":

```
a {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline; //* stands for IE7 and will not affect Chrome, Firefox and other browsers including IE8+
*zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! can't accept more than one answer but the IE7 'hack' is useful and definitely worth knowing.